# Passport JS local strategy returning 'Cannot set properties of undefined (setting location)' error

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

Passport JS is always returning an error

> Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'location') on Local Strategy

I have set up a local Strategy with passport 0.6.0 and Express 4.18.1

I have various functions going from the "login" click that triggers the following function :

```
login() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/auth/login/password';
    const body = {
        username: 'Clement_Alphaboy',
        password: 'test'
    };
    this.http.post(url, body).subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: (error) =>
        {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Of course, credentials are testing ones and are correct. I could retrieve them from document but preferred to input them like that to be sure they were correct. Then my route auth.js contains the local strategy :

```
passport.use("passport-local", new LocalStrategy({usernameField: "username", passwordField: "password"}, function verify(username, password, done) {
    db.sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE LOWER(nametag) = LOWER('" + username +"')", (row) => {
        let salt = bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        let user = row[0][0];
        crypto.pbkdf2(password, salt, 310000, 32, 'sha256', function (err, hashedPassword) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(user.password, "utf8"), hashedPassword)) {
                return done(null, false);
            }
            return done(null, user);
        });
    })
}));
```

The route post method :

```
router.post('/login/password', passport.authenticate('passport-local',
    { failureRedirect: '/login' },
    (req, res) => {
            response.redirect("/")
    })
);
```

and the serialization / deserialization functions :

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        cb(null, { id: user.id, username: user.username });
    });
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, cb) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        return cb(null, user);
    });
});
```

Can you maybe try to explain to me why am I getting the error

> "Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'location')"

whatever I am trying (given the right or wrong password...) and any tips on how to solve this will be welcomed.